# SYSWOW64 on windows: how windows api actually handled for 32 bit applications?

Tags: windows, kernel

If i write win32 api and run it on my windows 7 64bit. the loader will load wow dlls to my executable.
Now, If I call to virtualAlloc api, it will pass to WOW64cpu.dll that will convert the cpu-mod from 32 to 64 bit and will jump to the kernel.

If virtualAlloc returned 64-bit pointer that cannot be cast to 32 bit pointer, how will my 32bit executable will handle it?

Comment: What is your practical programming question? Are you having trouble with VirtualAlloc from a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS? Please show the code that is experiencing the problem so we can help solve it.

Comment: I just want to understand how SysWow works. Does the kernel have to know if the user application which did a syscall is 32 or 64? is it handled differently? or is it transparent to the kernel? VirtualAlloc is just an example of winapi I thought of...

Comment: I think this question is off topic. StackOverflow is for solving practical programming questions, not for satisfying curiosity about how things work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a practical, answerable problem.